# Can I load a Java class in a way that automatically removes its privileges?

Tags: java, security

I am working on developing a library that needs to instantiate and return untrusted objects downloaded from an external website. At a high-level, the library works as follows:

- Clients of the library requests a class from a remote source.
- My library instantiates that object, then returns it to the user.

This is a *major* security risk, since the untrusted code can do just about anything. To address this, my library has the following design:

- I enable the `SecurityManager` and, when instantiating the untrusted object, I use an `AccessController` to handle the instantiation in a context where there are no privileges.
- Before returning the object back to the client, I wrap the object in a decorator that uses an `AccessController` to forward all method requests to the underlying object in a way that ensures that the untrusted code is never run with any permissions.

It occurs to me, though, that this might not be the most elegant solution. Fundamentally, I want to strip away all permissions from any object of any type downloaded from the remote source. My current use of `AccessController` is simply a way of faking this up by intercepting all requests and dropping privileges before executing them. The `AccessController` approach also has its own issues:

- If the wrapped object has any methods that return objects, those returned objects have to themselves be wrapped.
- The wrapper code will potentially be thousands of lines long, since every exported method has to be secured.
- All of the methods exported by the downloaded object have to be known in advance in order to be wrapped.

My question is this: is there a way to load classes into the JVM (probably using a custom `ClassLoader`) such that any instances of those classes execute their methods with no permissions?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 I read your question and though it very interesting and the thing that came in my mind is the concept of SandBox. There is lots of articles on the internet about java sandBox, I'm do not know how to implement I just read about it. Looking forward to see what is the answers for this.

Comment: Here is the one that I read some time ago, I had it on my favorites, it is not exactly new, but it may help: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076945/java-security/understanding-the-keys-to-java-security----the-sandbox-and-authentication.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos That refers to the 1.1 model, the 1.2 model (released 1998) is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to call `defineClass` with an untrusted `ProtectionDomain`.

Your current solution has a number of problems. It doesn't appear to cover the static initialiser. It may be possible to install code into some mutable arguments. Methods that use the immediate caller will still be privileged (`AccessController.doPrivileged`, say). But most of all, it falls about when rubbing up against any kind of global - for instance running a finaliser.

Comment: That looks perfect. I didn't realize that this was an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there's a way to directly do what you asked, but I think your approach can be simplified by using interfaces and dynamic proxies. Basically, if you have an interface for the object to be returned, and all its methods return either simple types or interfaces, then you can wrap all the methods and their return values automatically, without knowing the methods in advance. Just implement an `InvocationHandler` that does the `AccessController` magic in its invoke method, and create proxies using `Proxy.newProxyInstance(...)`.

Comment: I forgot about Proxy. It's an interesting idea, though all objects are subclasses of an abstract base class and so this won't work directly. I'll see if I can make this work and report back.